# Can I show refresh Indicator even though I can't scroll the list view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In a page, my listView can be scrolled if I have at least 7 items or more. if there are only 3 items in my list then listView can not be scrolled.

I need to show Refresh Indicator (that circular indicator at the top of list) in my list even though I have less than 7 items (list can not be scrolled). How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: controller.items.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        },
      }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `physics` of the listView to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`

```
return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: controller.items.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        },

       }
   )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this if you don't wanna lose your clamping physics:

```
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
```

Answer (score -1):

As well as you can wrap your `Listview`, you can change this behavior so that the `ListView` only occupies the space it needs

```
return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: controller.items.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        },

       }
   )
```

Comment: `shrinkWrap` is a performance offender and shouldn't be used.